# Как с нескольких ячеек массива собрать данные в одну?

Tags: php

Как все данные в одну ячейку массива засунуть?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Должно быть $u = array( array потом обьект и тут все значения)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если предположить, что ваши данные получаются из декодирования json, то можно предложить следующий вариант:

```
$json = '[[{"mm":800}],[{"zip":"03894"}],[{"zxc":100}]]';

$data = json_decode($json, true);
array_walk_recursive($data, function($v, $k) use (&$result){ $result[$k] = $v; });
print_r($result);
```

на выходе

```
Array(
  [mm] => 800
  [zip] => 03894
  [zxc] => 100
)
```

В общем случае (и это пожалуй даже проще), можно поступить так:

```
$data = json_decode($json);

$result = [];
array_walk_recursive($data, function($v) use (&$result){ 
        $result += (array)$v;
});
```

*зы: здесь json используется только для создания указанной структуры объекта*

Comment: как переделать в array( array(stdclass)) В массиве массив и потом обьект и там уже эти значения

Comment: @Andrii чего чего? типа `[ [ stdClass{ mm, zip, zxc} ] ] ` ?

Comment: @Andrii `$result = [ [ (object)$result ] ]; print_r($result)` вы про это?

Comment: Решил, спасибо.